# Wysiwyg editor not showing with TinyMCE on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, tinymce, tinymce-4

I would like to use the TinyMCE gel in order to show a text editor while I'm creating my article.

Here is my set-up :
GEM file :

```
gem 'tinymce-rails'
```

I've created my tinymce.yml in config :

```
default:
  plugins:
    - image
    - link

alternate:
  selector: textarea.table-editor
  toolbar: styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | table
  plugins:
    - table
```

In application.js on top I added:

```
/= require tinymce
```

Here is my partial for the form :

```
<p>
 <%= f.text_area :text, :class => "tinymce",rows: 20, style: "width: 100%" %>
 <%= tinymce_assets %>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/tinymce.js"></script>
</p>
```

But the editor is not on the page, does anyone got an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Hiya - you make sure you use the "parent" tags like `ruby-on-rails` on your question and not just the version tags which have very few followers.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: You are right, I've got a message "Uncaught ReferenceError: TinyMCERails is not defined". I don't understand, I'm using the helper though

Comment: I edited, I added the <script> balise in my HTML file, I don't have any error in the console, but still I don't have the Wysiwyg in my text area, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have hit this issue:
https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/issues/238

TLDR: If you have created your own `app/assets/javascripts/timymce.js`, then you may be overwriting TinyMCERails' own file with the same name. Try renaming it, for example to `editor.js`.

Answer (score 0):

1. **you have to add in application.html.haml:**

= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js'

2. **text.html.haml** (add this js block in your haml file)

   :javascript
   tinymce.init({

   ```
         selector: '.tinymce',
         height: 500,
         menubar: false,
           toolbar: 'fontfamily | fontsize | forecolor'
       });
   ```
3. **add class "tinymce" in text_area_tag**

= text_area_tag 'client[case_instructions]', case_instructions, class: 'tinymce'